# Getting empty object list in ajax jquery while trying to bind dropdown in .net core

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am new to .net core and while using trying to bind Drop downs from ajax request but instead of Populated list i am getting the empty object list with full count

[image]

And this is my method which is returning a list.

[image]

I also tried to bind these with the Server-side but got this error.

[image]

Please guide me on why I am not able to bind these Dropdowns with any method I already tried.

Here is my code

```
public  JsonResult GetLevels() {

        // var list =  _levelsRepositry.GetAllLevels();



        var list = new List<ClassLevelModel>() {
        new ClassLevelModel(){Id = 1 , Level= "My Level1" },
        new ClassLevelModel(){Id = 1 , Level= "My Level2" },
        };

        return new JsonResult(list);
    }

    public JsonResult GetBoards()
    {

        var list = new List<BoardTypeModel>() {
        new BoardTypeModel(){Id = 1 , Board= "My Board" },
        new BoardTypeModel(){Id = 1 , Board= "My Board" },
        };

        return new JsonResult(list);
    }


     $(document).ready(function () {
                 GetLevels();
                 GetBoards();
    
            });
    
    
            function GetLevels() {
                $.ajax({
                    method: "Get",
                    url: "/Students/GetLevels",
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: true,
                    success: function (data) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            s += '<option value="' + data[i].Id + '">' + data[i].Level + '</option>';
                        }
                        $("#levels").html(s);
    
                    }
                });
    
            }
    
            function GetBoards() {
                $.ajax({
                    method: "Get",
                    url: "/Students/GetBoards",
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: true,
                    success: function (data) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            s += '<option value="' + data[i].Id + '">' + data[i].Board + '</option>';
                        }
                        $("#boards").html(s);
    
                    }
                });
    
            }
```

Comment: Please note these methods were async and I thought maybe this would be a reason so I removed Task<> and async But this was also not the problem and I am still badly stuck on this drop-down issue.

Comment: Please edit your post and show the actual code as text instead of screenshots. Others can't copy and paste from your images. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) for details.

Comment: + use the edit link on your question to add additional information.

Comment: I have added the code

Answer (score 1):

be sure that your startup file has  a right configuration for the controllers

```
    services.AddControllersWithViews()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
           options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver =
              new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver());
```

Be sure that your model class properties have {get; set;}

And you have a syntax error in your java code. Define s

```
 var s = '<option value="-1">Please Select Level </option>';
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  s += '<option value="' + data[i].id + '">' + data[i].level + '</option>';
  }

$('#levels').html(s);
```

and view

```
<select class="form-control" id="levels" ></select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have used ViewBag in your view,you only need to set `ViewBag` before `return View` rather than using ajax.Here is a demo:
Action:

```
public IActionResult AddStudent()
        {
            ViewBag.BoardsList = new List<BoardTypeModel>() {
        new BoardTypeModel(){Id = 1 , Board= "My Board1" },
        new BoardTypeModel(){Id = 2 , Board= "My Board2" },
        };
            ViewBag.LevelsList = new List<ClassLevelModel>() {
        new ClassLevelModel(){Id = 1 , Level= "My Level1" },
        new ClassLevelModel(){Id = 2 , Level= "My Level2" },
        };
            return View();
        }
```

View:

```
<form>
    <select asp-for="BoardId" asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.BoardsList,"Id","Board"))">
        <option value="0">Select Board</option>
    </select>
    <select asp-for="LevelId" asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.LevelsList,"Id","Level"))">
        <option value="0">Select Level</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

result:
[image]